# How to handle simple inputs in Kattis with F#?

Tags: io, f#

I am very new to F# and Kattis. I have tried this simple problem "Which is greater" at Kattis. Link is here: https://open.kattis.com/problems/whichisgreater

I have tried with this code:

```
open System

let a = Console.Read()
let b = Console.Read()
if a > b then Console.WriteLine "1" else Console.WriteLine "0"
```

But I still get wrong answer. Anybody who can help on how to handle inputs and outputs in Kattis for F#? Maybe some simple examples can be made available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is accepted by Kattis:

```ml
open System

let line = Console.ReadLine().Split ' '
let a = int64 line.[0]
let b = int64 line.[1]
Console.WriteLine(if a > b then 1 else 0)
```

Here, we read the line, split it on a space character into two numbers, compare them and print the required result.

Comment: That's interesting - an explicit entry point isn't required after all. I'm surprised this solution is accepted, though, because you're not converting the input strings into integers. I guess they're not testing for cases like "11111 2".

Comment: Good call. I don't know anything about F#. Conversions added.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they're using an [old version of the F# compiler](https://open.kattis.com/help/fsharp), so you have to specify an [explicit entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/entry-point#explicit-entry-point). Here's their [sample F# solution for a different problem](https://open.kattis.com/download/different/different.fs):

```ml
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    (fun _ -> Console.ReadLine()) |>
    Seq.initInfinite |>
    Seq.takeWhile ((<>) null) |>
    Seq.iter
       (fun (s : string) ->
            let arr = s.Split([|' '|])
            let a = int64 arr.[0]
            let b = int64 arr.[1]
            /// solve test case and output answer
            printfn "%d" (abs (a - b))
       )
    0
```

I think that should give you enough info to solve the "which is greater" problem you're looking at. (Note that `Console.Read` only reads a single character, so it's not what you want for this problem. Instead, you probably want to read in the entire line, then split it into two strings at the blank space, then convert each of those strings into an integer. Coincidentally, the sample code I pasted above does something similar.)